# How to avoid java files from classes directory/jar file?

Tags: java, file, deployment, jar, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea v11.4 and when I compile my project in the target/classes directory not only class files are listed but java files too. For every class file I find the corresponding java file...is this the right behaviour?

In my project I use maven to create the projects jar file and this jar file contains these java files too.

How can I prevent the java files from being copied in the jar file? I want to obfuscate the jar file to publish it in the net so if the java files are part of it too the obfuscation becomes useless.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [guide](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/):
You should build the Jar file using **Build | Build Artifact** menu item.
Note that by default all libraries are extracted to the target Jar. It became possible with addition of the new **Extracted Directory** element. Using such element you can extract a directory from a Jar file and place it into the output of your artifact:

Comment: I want to build the Jar via Maven, not from Idea, to automate it on a CI server. My question is why does Idea copy all java files in the _target/classes_ folder...from where there are packaged into the Jar by Maven?

Comment: There are 2 options as I see it: 1 - you need to edit exclude directories at level of Idea project settings (not to copy the source files to target) ; 2 - check your Pom.xml and if needed fix the copy instructions for maven jar plugin ( I think you can exclude files by extensions from copy section in jar plugin definitions)

Comment: If I compile the project with maven everything is fine...I always have class files in the _target/classes_ folder only. The problem is Idea but I don't know where to exclude the java files. I've created the project from scratch and got the same result. Any help appreciated...

Comment: Creating project from scratch with the defective module as master (have multiple modules) works. Thanks aviad for helping out!